# AngularJS: Determining Template based on Select Control

Tags: angularjs

I was just thrown for a loop by scope creep/change on this project.

Initially there were 6 buttons on a page (with other stuff) triggering routes to 6 different Add New ... Forms. I had all the buttons wired to the routes and working.

On Friday, the UIX leader decided that the landing page was too complex and convinced the stakeholders that a single "ADD NEW REQUEST" button was needed leading to a drop down wherein the user could choose the correct form.

So my template looks like this:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <label for="requestType">What type of request would you like to create?
                <span class="required">*</span>
            </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="requestType" ng-model="requestType" ng-change="new_form_select()">
                <option value="0">Please Select ...</option>
                <option value="1">IT Web Task</option>
                <option value="2">SAP Task</option>
                <option value="3">Email Campaign</option>
                <option value="4">Third Party Suppression</option>
                <option value="5">Report Request</option>
                <option value="6">Other / I'm Not Sure</option>                        
            </select>
         </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

I have templates of webtask.html, saptask.html, campaign.html, suppression.html, report.html, generalrequest.html.

I realized when I got this far that I don't have a clue what to do next. Should I put all of those forms on the same page hidden and show them based on the selection (can I even do that?) or should I make the select sort of a page jump menu and load the applicable form when selected (do I do that in the controller?)

OMG, I am lost!

Needless to say, this is my first Angular Project ... I used to use pure jQuery and am learning AngularJS.

Any guidance is GREATLY appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't solve this problem for you but I can guide you through the main steps of a simple solution:

1. Take a look at [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)
2. The method called on your select ng-change would redirect to the state for the selected form:

   ```
   <select class="form-control"
           name="requestType"
           ng-model="requestType"
           ng-change="new_form_select()">

       <option value="0">Please Select ...</option>
       <option value="webtask">IT Web Task</option>
       <option value="saptask">SAP Task</option>
       ....  
   </select>

   $scope.new_form_select = function() {
       if(requestType) {
           location.href = '#/' + requestType;
       }
   }
   ```
3. You now need to define the states and link the templates. Angular-UI-Router has a few examples in it's documentation but it would be something like:

   ```
   .state('webtask', {
       url: "/webtask",
       templateUrl: "templates/webtask.html",
       controller: function() {

       }
   })
   .state('saptask', {
       url: "/saptask",
       templateUrl: "templates/saptask.html",
       controller: function() {

       }
   })
   // you get the idea..
   ```
4. Now you need to add the markup where these templates will be placed in your page. Again Angular-UI-Router has a few examples on how this can be done:

   ```
   <body>
       <!-- Your select could be here -->

       <!-- The selected template would appear here -->
       <div ui-view></div>
   </body>
   ```

Of course you need to add the $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider in the config for your main controller but all this is explained in the Angular-UI-Router page.

Comment: Since Angular-UI-Router is still in Beta and warning that the API might change, is it safe to implement with this solution? (I did read about it last night and also saw Angular-Route-Segment as a possibility ... and I am not looking for anyone to do this for me, I need to learn it and I appreciate your input

Comment: Most angular plugins are in beta and will remain like this for a long time. If you fear that the plugin might change, well then you should also fear that Angular will change. You don't need to use the latest version of any library/plugin unless it is a security release and even then it depends. Since creating your own routing plugin is out of the question(time is required), I think this is your best choice.